# Perform some action when tabbing between labels?

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, label, transparent

I know that label can't receive focus, it doesn't seem to be responsive to tab switching. But all I need is perform some action when user uses tab consequently on a form which has only labels. For example, each label has an associated textbox but this textbox is hidden when the label is visible and vice-versa. What I want is allowing user to use tab to switch between the hidden textboxes on the form, normally, all the textboxes are hidden while all the labels are shown, the labels are supposed to be focusable so that when using tab, it can know that (as some event) to show the associated textbox and hide itself, when switching to another label, the current label whose the associated textbox is shown will become visible again and its associated textbox will become hidden.

I have to implement this kind of 2 in 1 control (textbox and label in a composited control) because I just want to show only the text (no border and background) as if the textbox has a transparent background and only show the textbox (and hide the label) when user need to edit (start by clicking on the field or using tab). This should have been easier for me if there was a transparent background textbox but there isn't a decent one in the world of windows forms. Please notice that I also know of the **alpha blend transparent textbox presented in an article in codeproject** but it can't meet my need because the text is rendered wrong with ugly border around the text path (some kind of missing antialiasing but it's even worse than that).

I'm really pity if this mechanism can't be implemented, the forms look better when all the fields seem to show info only but a click or tab switch can let user jump in edit mode.
I hope there is some solution out there. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you have some gradiented or picture background that means you can't just use a normal text box and set the back colour and border style?

Comment: Can't you just monitor key presses?

Comment: @JamesB Yes, the parent background of the textbox is gradiented (not solid color) so changing the backcolor of the textbox according to the parent background won't help.

Comment: @DeeMac I thought of this idea but the implementation is a little complicated when I have to add listeners to TAB and SHIFT + TAB and remember the current position, implement some kind of Tab index for my own controls on the forms. I've not tried it yet because of hoping for some cleaner solution. Thanks.

Comment: It's not really too complicated. You cannot tab between labels, the relevant properties such as TabStop are useless on that class. All you'd have to do is monitor the tab key on the control that is currently visible (as I understand only one textbox will be displayed at one time).

Comment: @DeeMac yes, that's the effect I want (it's interesting enough to encourage me to try to achieve this), maybe I'll try that approach. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this solution by a whim in my mind. I didn't think there was such a solution but it does help solve my problem (and I'm sure many others will benefit from it). Simply I have to create my own Label inheriting **UserControl**. I didn't thought of **UserControl** before and it is very helpful. Focusability, transparent background, borderlessness are all which can be done easily to a **UserControl**. The only custom feature I have to do myself is rendering the text which is also very simple and there are many ways to do. I just add a Label to the **UserControl** and set Label's Dock to DockStyle.Fill, adjust the height of the **UserControl** properly and that's all.

Thank God helping me think of UserControl before trying any other complicated solution such as listening to TAB and SHIFT + TAB keypress events.